# PUT Data on HDFS via HTTP WEB API

Tags: python, webhdfs

I'm trying to implement a PUT request on HDFS via the HDFS Web API.

So I looked up the Documentation on how to do that : https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html#CREATE

First do a PUT without redirect, to get a 307, catch the new URL and then PUT on that URL with DATA.

When I do my first put, I do get the 307, but the URL is the same has the first one. So I'm note sure if I'm already on the "good" datanode or not.

Any way, I get this URL and try to add DATA to it, but I get an error, from what I understand, it is a connection error. Host is cutting down the connection.

```
class HttpFS:
    def __init__(self, url=settings.HTTPFS_URL):
        self.httpfs = url
        self.auth = HTTPKerberosAuth(mutual_authentication=OPTIONAL)

    def put(self, local_file, hdfs_dir):
        url = "{}{}".format(self.httpfs, hdfs_dir)
        params = {"op": "CREATE", "overwrite": True}
        print(url)
        r = requests.put(url, auth=self.auth, params=params, stream=True, verify=settings.CA_ROOT_PATH, allow_redirects=False)

        r = requests.put(r.headers['Location'], auth=self.auth, data=open(local_file, 'rb'), params=params, stream=True, verify=settings.CA_ROOT_PATH)
```

Here is the error given:

```
    r = requests.put(r.headers['Location'], auth=self.auth, data=open(local_file, 'rb'), params=params, stream=True, verify=settings.CA_ROOT_PATH)
  File "/home/cdsw/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 134, in put
    return request('put', url, data=data, **kwargs)
  File "/home/cdsw/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/cdsw/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/cdsw/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/cdsw/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe'))
```

Edit 1:

I tried also with https://github.com/pywebhdfs/pywebhdfs repos. Since it is supposed to do exactly what i'm looking for. But I still have this Broken Pipe Error.

```
from requests_kerberos import OPTIONAL, HTTPKerberosAuth
from pywebhdfs.webhdfs import PyWebHdfsClient
from utils import settings
auth = HTTPKerberosAuth(mutual_authentication=OPTIONAL)

url = f"https://{settings.HDFS_HTTPFS_HOST}:{settings.HDFS_HTTPFS_PORT}/webhdfs/v1/"

hdfs_client = PyWebHdfsClient(base_uri_pattern=url, request_extra_opts={'auth':auth, 'verify': settings.CA_ROOT_PATH})
with open(data_dir + file_name, 'rb') as file_data:
            hdfs_client.create_file(hdfs_path + file_name, file_data=file_data, overwrite=True)
```

Same error:

```
    hdfs_client.create_file(hdfs_path + file_name, file_data=file_data, overwrite=True)
  File "/home/cdsw/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pywebhdfs/webhdfs.py", line 115, in create_file
    **self.request_extra_opts)
  File "/home/cdsw/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 134, in put
    return request('put', url, data=data, **kwargs)
  File "/home/cdsw/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/cdsw/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/cdsw/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/cdsw/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe'))
```

Edit 2:

I found out I was sending too much data at once. So now I create a file on HDFS, then I append to it with chunk of data. But it is slow... And I still can get the same error as above randomly. The bigger are the are the chunk the more I have chances to get a `Connection aborted`. My files more in range of 200Mb, so it take ages comparing to the Hadoop binary "hdfs dfs -put"

Comment: Was it responsive with Curl?

Comment: I tried once, but didn't know how to add the Kerberos inside my curl, so I got rejected by host.

Comment: I get the same error when using https://github.com/pywebhdfs/pywebhdfs. Might be a host configuration issue.